# How to combine standard Java and Android code into a single library?

Tags: java, android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, osgi

How to best organize the structure of such a library?

- which build system to use (gradle or maven)?
- will it be a single project, compiled and packed once for each JVM?
- will it be 3 projects: mylib-core, mylib-java, mylib-android?
- how to build, pack and distribute the library (or libraries)?
- does it sense to use OSGi or Spring?

### Minimal Code Sample

A library with a single API, compatible with, and equal for Java SE and Android.

API:

```
/*
 * Given a fonts name, size (height) and a text,
 * the library returns the doubled (<- arbitrary) width of the text in pixels.
 */
int fetchTextWidthDoubled(String fontName, int fontSize, String text);
```

While the doubling of the size is common code and should not be duplicated,
the code to fetch font metrics is different in Android and Java SE.

Assuming i have two classes implemented with the required code like this:

Java SE:

```
public class JavaSeTextWidthFetcher implements TextWidthFetcher {
    @Override
    public int fetchTextWidth(String fontName, int fontSize, String text) {
        // something with java.awt.Font
    }
}
```

Android:

```
public class AndroidTextWidthFetcher implements TextWidthFetcher {
    @Override
    public int fetchTextWidth(String fontName, int fontSize, String text) {
        // something with android.graphics.Paint.FontMetrics
    }
}
```

and the API implementation roughly like this:

```
public class DoubleTextWidthFetcher

    private TextWidthFetcher impl;

    @Override
    public int fetchTextWidthDoubled(String fontName, int fontSize, String text) {
        return 2 * impl.fetchTextWidth(fontName, fontSize, text);
    }
}
```

Comment: you want choice inside a library?

Comment: not sure if i understand what you are asking. what i want: a library that works on both android and java SE, using the same API, and it should be as simple and comfortable as possible to integrate into other projects.